# Find and return in custom structure in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have this data in my `collection`:

```
{ id: 1, age: 5, name: "Nick" }
{ id: 2, age: 7, name: "John" }
{ id: 3, age: 2, name: "Anna" }
{ id: 4, name: "Peter", children: [1,2,5] }
{ id: 5, age: 25, name: "Mat", children: [3] }
```

I want a query that will return the ***people that have children***, *ordered by* their `age`, in this form:

```
[
 { id: 4, name: "Peter", children: [
   { /* Nick's record */ },
   { /* John's record */ },
   { /* Mat's record */ }
 ] },
 { id: 5, name: "Mat", age: 25, children: [
   { /* Anna's record */ }
 ] }
]
```

**Note:** People in the `children` array of the response should also be ordered by their `age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below Query:

```
db.collection.find({children:{$exists:1}}).sort({age:1}).forEach(
            function(doc){
                      var printdoc = doc;
                      printdoc.children = db.collection.find(
                                        { id: { $in: doc.children }
                                        }).sort({age:1}).toArray();
              printjson(printdoc);
});
```

This will provide you the below required output :

```
{
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "Peter",
        "children" : [
                {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "age" : 5,
                        "name" : "Nick"
                },
                {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "age" : 7,
                        "name" : "John"
                },
                {
                        "id" : 5,
                        "age" : 25,
                        "name" : "Mat",
                        "children" : [
                                3
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "id" : 5,
        "age" : 25,
        "name" : "Mat",
        "children" : [
                {
                        "id" : 3,
                        "age" : 2,
                        "name" : "Anna"
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query would retrieve the documents which have children. But this won't retrieve records of children, you have to populate these records by making another query. Real joins like in sql is not possible in mongodb.

```
db.yourCollection.find({"children.0": {$exists:true}}).sort({age:1})
```

There is another feature as Database References which can be used for fetching data from another collection using its ids. But you have to change your data structure to use them. Check out the following for more information: [Database References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation)